# WPF TreeView не обновляется при обновлении ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть следующий код XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeitems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Normal">
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:TreeModel}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RelatedItems}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding CollapsedImageSource}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding CollapsedImageSource}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubsubItems}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding CollapsedImageSource}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MouseDown="lbCarotages_PreviewMouseDown">
                                    <Image x:Name="nodeImg" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding LeftImageSource}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                                    <Image Width="16" Margin="0 0 5 0" Source="{Binding Path=Name, ConverterParameter=Curve, Converter={StaticResource convCurveDefinedToImage}}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Формирую Items = new ObservableCollection();

TreeModel:

```
public class TreeModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value;
            OnPropChng("Name");
        }
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage CollapsedImageSource { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ExpandedImageSource { get; set; }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeModel1> _relatedItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeModel1>();
    public ObservableCollection<TreeModel1> RelatedItems
    {
        get { return _relatedItems; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropChng(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

public class TreeModel1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage CollapsedImageSource { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ExpandedImageSource { get; set; }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeModel2> _subItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeModel2>();

    public ObservableCollection<TreeModel2> SubItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _subItems;
        }
    }

}

public class TreeModel2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage CollapsedImageSource { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ExpandedImageSource { get; set; }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<TreeModel3> _subsubItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeModel3>();

    public ObservableCollection<TreeModel3> SubsubItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _subsubItems;
        } 
    }
}

public class TreeModel3
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage LeftImageSource { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefined { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда дерево отображается идеально.

Но когда меняю что-нить в Items, элементарно Items[0].Name = "новое наименование" TreeView не изменяется.

Не могу разобраться что к чему.

Comment: Элементы в Items реализуют интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошим дополнением к ответам о реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged` на моделях будет совет о задании значений свойств в сеттере через метод `SetProperty`, [как это сделано в **Prism**](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs).

```
protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
{ 
    if (Equals(storage, value)) return false; 

    storage = value; 
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName); 

    return true; 
}
```

Идея в том, чтобы пробрасывать событие изменения свойства только в случае его реального изменения (а не по факту вызова сеттера). В самом деле, в некоторых случаях лишние вызовы события могут создавать лаги интерфейса.

Пример использования:

```
public object Prop
{
    get
    {
        return _prop;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _prop, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

наследуем классы от интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`

добавляем event `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

и метод

```
protected bool NotifiyPropertyChanged<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string property = "")
{
  if (oldValue == null && newValue == null) return false;
  if (oldValue != null && newValue != null)
    if (oldValue is byte[] && newValue is byte[])
      if ((oldValue as byte[]).Count() == (newValue as byte[]).Count())
        if ((newValue as byte[]).SequenceEqual((oldValue as byte[])))
          return false;
  if (!(oldValue is byte[]) || !(newValue is byte[]))
    if (Equals(oldValue, newValue))
      return false;
  oldValue = newValue;
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
  return true;
}
```

при изменении любого из свойств вызывать его. Например:

```
protected string m_Name = "";
public string Name { 
  get {return m_Name; }
  set { NotifiyPropertyChanged(ref m_Name, value); }
}
```

в Вашем случае не все классы наследуются от интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`

UPD: спасибо Gardes за `CallerMemberName`

UPD: dm.dymov за `<T>`

UPD: Добавлен Equals для byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу @Дмитрий Чистик

Еще одна реализация интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged, более удобная. Не приходиться заботится о передаче имени свойства в метод и соблюдении правильности написания.

```
public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
public class TreeModelVM : BaseVM
{
    private string _name = string.Empty;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return _name; } 
        set
        {   
            if (_name != value)
            { 
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there)

Comment: @dm.dymov, это чистая случайность)

Comment: Я не знаю почему все тиражируют вот эту проверку на  `null` : `var handler = PropertyChanged; if (handler != null)`? Хотя же есть правильный принцип работы с событиями через `null object pattern`, делается это так: `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };` и больше не нужно перед вызовом события проверять наличие подписантов. Хорошее [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocozoCVox-c&list=PLuGqgO5WmeGMagq_MPZxgOW7mQJ8Yxk_z) на эту тему.

Comment: @Bulson, а можно узнать дефиницию слова "правильный"? Проверка на null не работает? Господа на enSO приводят следующие аргумент против null object: 1) кто-то случайно может убрать инициализацию хэндлера по незнанию 2) могут быть проблемы с сериализацией/десериализацией. А для C# 6 [Roslyn wiki советует/ожидает](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators) `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);`.

Comment: @dm.dymov По п. 1) да, такое может случится, а кто-то может еще и хуже чего-нибудь сделать по незнанию, но вероятность этого не должна нас останавливать в желании правильно работать с событиями. По п.2) что-то я не помню чтобы события сериализовывались, хотя может я не прав. Та ссылка, которую вы дали она хорошая, но она является примером для тех, кто привык делать по-старинке через `var handler = PropertyChanged`. Вам не понравилась моя категоричность? Да, ради бога, делайте как вам сподручнее. Но, знать о других возможностях, я думаю, должно быть полезно.

Comment: @Bulson, я пытаюсь сказать, что тут слово "правильный", мягко говоря, неуместно, потому что оно предполагает, что другие методы неправильные, а это не так, относительно тех, которые здесь обсуждаются. Знать о других возможностях хорошо, заниматься крестовыми походами - не очень.

Comment: @dm.dymov и я, и я, и я такого же мнения :)