# Отследить изменение свойств объекта

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть коллекция вида `ObservableCollection<BaseClass> Project {get;set;}`.

Задача в следующем:

Если какое-то свойство объекта изменилось, то нужно уведомить пользователя о том, что в проект внесены правки и его требуется сохранить.

Ничего не придумал, кроме как реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` у базового класса, но классов достаточно много и каждое свойство разворачивать в свойство с полем, чтобы вызывать `OnPropertyChanged` довольно муторно.

Существует ли какая-нибудь лаконичная альтернатива?

Comment: посмотрите это пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652866/185848

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, Честно говоря, не понял в чем разница. Сейчас у меня свойства классов и без того выглядят так: `public string Name {get {return _name}; set {_name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }`

Comment: там разве что упрощена схема переопределения. У меня ушел час чтобы 200 свойств под это пример переделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Альтернативой ручной реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged` будет либо использование сниппетов, либо использование специализированных инструментов для инъекции IL-кода в сборку при компиляции. Общепризнанным лидером в этой области является [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), но он, естественно, платный. Тем не менее существует опенсурс проект для изменения сборок при компиляции под названием [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/), [одно из дополнений которого](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) позволяет делать как раз реализацию `INF`. Кстати, советую ознакомиться с полным списком дополнений для Fody на странице в GitHub, там много интересного. Также можно писать свои дополнения, схема разработки не очень дружелюбная, но зато есть множество примеров (все существующие дополнения также лежат на GitHub).

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901921/observablecollection-and-item-propertychanged):

Создаёте коллекцию, все элементы коллекции при таком подходе должны реализовывать `INPC`.

```
ObservableCollection<INotifyPropertyChanged> items = 
                              new ObservableCollection<INotifyPropertyChanged>();
```

Вешаете обработчик на событие изменений в коллекции:

```
items.CollectionChanged += 
    new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
                                                        items_CollectionChanged);
```

В делегате пробегаемся по старым/новым элементам и убираем/добавляем обработчики изменения свойств в объектах:

```
static void items_CollectionChanged(object sender, 
               System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
        item.PropertyChanged -= new 
                               PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);

    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
        item.PropertyChanged += 
                           new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
}
```

Собственно внутри этого метода напишите код уведомления:

```
static void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Ну и каждое свойство самого объекта, входящего в коллекцию должно быть связано с интерфейсом `INPC`. Для более ёмкой и читаемой реализации свойств внутри объекта воспользуйтесь сторонними библиотеками, например `MVVM Light`.

Comment: Если объекты в коллекции долгоживущие, нужно не забыть пробежаться по ней и отписаться в конце использования.

Comment: Потому что даже `Clear()` не присылает `OldItems`.

Comment: Да и вообще всё, что будет вызывать Action.Reset в коллекции, поведет к утечкам.

Comment: @klutch1991, С этим мне все ясно. Я имел ввиду, может быть есть какой-то иной подход, который позволит реализовать все более кратко. Не хочется несколько сотен свойств разворачивать в свойство с приватным полем. Может подскажете что-то в плане краткой записи `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Наподобие [PostSharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-mvvmlight).

Comment: От `backing field` никуда не уйти. Слышал, что для C#7 (или даже ещё более поздних релизов) обещали добавить какие-то упрощения, которые могли бы помочь с решением этой задачи, а вообще говоря, закрытое поле нужно в любом случае. Вместе с тем, можете написать свой сниппет, который будет автоматически генерировать нужную Вам конструкцию кода. Я обычно пользовался сниппетом.

Comment: @maxwell, [Fody + PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). Делает штуку, аналогичную PostSharp, при компиляции инъецирует IL-реализацию `INF` с различными эвристиками.

Comment: @dm.dymov, То, что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @maxwell, могу как ответ оформить?

Comment: @dm.dymov, Да, можете.

Comment: @maxwell, сделано.